# Why is this pointer invalid?

Tags: c

```
char* x = malloc(512);
memset(x, 0, 513);
free(x);
```

Why is this crashing the program? It is saying `free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000614010`
That doesn't make any sense, if anything it should be ruining some other random part of the program because it writes into undefined memory space.

Comment: [Nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've caused undefined behaviour, so *anything* can happen.  In this case, it's possible that your `free()` implementation might be checking for some information in the space immediately after your buffer.  Since you overwrote it, it's game over.

Comment: @Carl Oh God, that is nasty. I always just thought "undefined" meant: "well there could be some crash". Looks like vendors just implement random stuff in those occasions instead! Very helpful realization.

Comment: @Blub: Eehm, __no__. Would you rather have the error `free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000614010` or a BSOD? Exactly. You should be glad that you even got an error message.

Comment: @nightcracker I am glad, I just meant the whole situation was nasty. Sry for the confusion?

Comment: @all. Why I am not getting any crash on my Linux PC. Its "checking for some information in the space immediately after your buffer". But here code is not referring space after buffer.

Comment: @Alam, Undefined behaviour means jut that - undefined.  Anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new, but I hope I can answer this question to your satisfaction.

You are provoking undefined behaviour by overwriting a vital part of your allocated chunk. You are deleting the first (upper byte) of the size information on that chunk, that is written by `malloc`. Most C Standard Libraries use the [Doug Lea Malloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) that appends and prepends some bytes to your chunk, that hold size and usage information. By overriding this, you actually destroy the information that `free()` call needs to succeed and really free the malloc'd memory. Some implementations of `malloc` don't do that and reserve an 'Out-Of-Band' Table (somewhere else where you don't override it) for the chunk alignments and sizes, and some just prepend / append that information. Your program crashes, like I said, because you override vital information without which `free()` just can't do what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

You're `malloc`ing `512` bytes, and you're writing with `memset` 513 bytes, so you've corrupted the heap.

If it's not already somehow obvious, it's undefined behaviour. You crash because you overflowed the heap and wrote over an important address that's used in managing the structure of the heap.

Comment: -1, This answer is about as useful as _"you're adding 1 to x"_ is useful to a question containing _"x += 1"_.

Comment: @nightcracker: This answer is fine; the implication is "you're invoking undefined behaviour".  The other answers that posit an explanation are just speculating.

Comment: @nightcracker I could explicitly state that you're causing undefined behaviour, but I thought that was obvious. Anyway I read the question literally and the reason why is because he's corrupting the heap by writing 1 too many bytes.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: This answer is just repeating the facts stated in the question without conclusion or further explanation. I will remove my -1 if you add at least some words about UB.

Comment: @nightcracker I guess you're right, I interpreted the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated 512 bytes of memory, but are writing 513 bytes to it. `free()` is presumably checking that the memory area is still valid (and won't be if it includes guard bytes that you have written over).

Answer (score 0):

It is common for heap allocators to place some book-keeping information immediately before and/or after the memory allocated.  One possible explanation for your observation is that you have overwritten some data essential to the operation of the memory allocator,  perhaps the size of the chunk allocated or the location of the next free space.

In any case, writing outside the bounds of the your allocated space is undefined behavior, and anything can happen.  Just because this is what happens now doesn't mean it's what will happen on a different system, or even on the same system at a different time.  Conversely, even when you don't see errors, that doesn't mean undefined behavior is not invoked.  This is the cost of using an unsafe language such as C.